# mapping keys in .Xresources not working

Tags: command-line, keyboard, vim

I'm mapping keys such as `Ctrl+Shift+a` to send a particular string that way vim can receive it.

`~/.Xresourcs`

```
XTerm.vt100.translations: #override \
  Ctrl ~Meta Shift <Key>a: string(0x1b) string("[65;5u") \n\
  Ctrl ~Meta Shift <Key>b: string(0x1b) string("[66;5u") \n\
  Ctrl ~Meta Shift <Key>f: string(0x1b) string("[70;5u")
```

`.vimrc`

```
 map <ESC>[65;5u   :echo "ctrl-shift-a received"<CR>
```

Then I load the file `xrdb ~/.Xresources`. When I press `Ctrl+Shift+a` in vim, nothing was printed at the bottom left of vim.

My  $TERM is `xterm-256color`

Comment: I don't use vim but I paste text snippets into various application windows. For example, I have a script called `console.sh` which has `#! /usr/bin/env bash` on the first line and `bash -c 'sleep 0.2; xdotool type "[CONSOLE][/CONSOLE]" && xdotool key Left Left Left Left Left Left Left Left Left Left'` on the second line. I bound that using my desktop environments shortcuts GUI to `Ctrl+Shift+K`. One pressing that keyboard combination in any window that can receive text, I get `[CONSOLE][/CONSOLE]` as the output with the insertion cursor located between the two tags.

Answer (score 1):

- In `Xresources`:

  *This point has been edited in the question and is now correct.*

  There was a blank space after the backslash in the third line.
  It should be removed, otherwise the backslash will not escape the literal newline character.

  ```
  Ctrl ~Meta Shift <Key>b: string(0x1b) string("[66;5u") \n\
  ```
- In `vimrc`:

  Use `nnoremap` instead of `map`.

  ```
  nnoremap <ESC>[65;5u :echo "ctrl-shift-a received"<CR>
  ```

Comment: Removed the extra blank space, so loading with xrdb results in no warnings. However I still have the issue that keybindings are not being recognized, either vim is not receiving the string or xterm is not reading the file.